# A delete/trash all function?

Tags: customization

Is there a function (or a predefined set of functions) that will clear all posts, post tags and categories, all custom posts and custom post terms, attachments, menus and customizer settings?

So far I know how to delete all theme mods with

`remove_theme_mods()`

I found [wp_delete_post()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post) but this needs post ID I guess, since when I called it empty nothing happened.

I need a function that will quickly delete or trash all of the above, because I'm working on an import, so every time I import something I need to go to each page and delete everything manually, and this is tedious. It would save me time if I could do it in a single click/refresh.

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18271951/1908141)?

Comment: Note that plugin recommendations are off-topic, you can ask how to do something, but you can't ask for software recommendations here as a question needs to have a definitive answer

Comment: I updated my question to remove plugin recommendations.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I'd rather not mess with the database tables manually, if I delete something by accident I'd need to do everything from scratch :\

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't find anything so I created this. The only drawback is that it will delete the 'Uncategorized' term in the Posts, but I can live with this since it's just for development purpose.

```
function delete_all(){
    global $wpdb;
    $menus = get_terms( 'nav_menu', array( 'hide_empty' => false ) );
    $all_post_types = get_post_types();
    $all_taxonomies = get_taxonomies();
    $all_options = wp_load_alloptions();

    foreach ($all_options as $option) {
        delete_option($option);
    }

    foreach ($menus as $menu => $menu_obj) {
        wp_delete_nav_menu($menu_obj->term_id);
    }

    foreach ($all_post_types as $post_type => $post_type_value) {
        $temp_posts = get_posts( array('post_type' => $post_type, 'posts_per_page' => -1));

        foreach ($temp_posts as $temp_post => $temp_post_value) {
            wp_delete_post($temp_post_value->ID);
        }
    }

    remove_theme_mods();

    foreach ( $all_taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        // Prepare & excecute SQL - also deletes Uncategorized
        $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "DELETE t.*, tt.* FROM $wpdb->terms AS t INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('%s')", $taxonomy ) );

    }

}

add_action('wp_loaded', 'delete_all');
```

The taxonomy part I found here: http://wpsmith.net/2014/plugin-uninstall-delete-terms-taxonomies-wordpress-database/

I looked at `wp_delete_term`, but I coulnd't get it to work.

Comment: I would recommend adding a big warning text with a backup reminder, into the code, since your code snippet might be copied/pasted out of context  ;-)

Comment: I do agree with @birgire here. And it is really really very important to add such notices when you post code that can irreversably completely trash a site

Comment: Oh, this won't go into production, this is on my local server, because I'm testing a plugin functionality, so I just need to delete everything when I need it. But yeah, I do agree with you both, if I'll post this on github or somewhere I'll make sure to add multiple warnings :)